# Store timestamp for first insertion when using UpsertItemAsync?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Using C#, I want to store a property containing a timestamp for when the item was first inserted. When I insert the item, I don't know if there already is an item with that same id in the container. Can it be done without first calling readItem to check if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but the possible solution(s) are probably more complicated than doing a read first since there is no system property that stores the creation timestamp of a document.

If you truly want to handle this outside your code, you could take a look at [stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript)